# elasticsearch return document on update

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get the updated document after update operation.

Using elasticsearch version `7.0.0`.

I tried :

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/dmf_product_match/_doc/YKsu3m0BxrmuyWilMQ-I/_update?fields=_source' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "name" : "new_name"
    }
}'
```

But get this error.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/dmf_product_match/_doc/YKsu3m0BxrmuyWilMQ-I/_update] contains unrecognized parameter: [fields]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/dmf_product_match/_doc/YKsu3m0BxrmuyWilMQ-I/_update] contains unrecognized parameter: [fields]"},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/dmf_product_match/_update/YKsu3m0BxrmuyWilMQ-I?_source' -d '{
    "doc" : {
        "name" : "new_name"
    }
}'
```

You could also use `"doc_as_upsert" : true`. Reference: [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert)